# How to Create connection on visual Studio 2008 Ado.Net Entity Data Model to Sql Server 2012

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2008, ado.net, oledb

I want to create connection from visual studio 2008 to sql server 2012 by Ado.Net Entity data model,but I got this error at  this photo [support error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Rz0S.jpg)

I tried to find a solution to this problem and I thought maybe OLEDB can be a solution but in this photo I want to choose .Net Framework Data Provider for OLEDB below to solve the problem by OLEDB but there is no selection of it. [no selection of OLEDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7t2F1.jpg)

So please can you tell me how can I make connection vs2008 through ado.net or how I can select OLEDB because I need a web service to my smart device application. Because it is a smart device application I can only use VS2008 to develop. I am looking forward to hear from you. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can develop the web service using any newer VS version, it is not tied to the Smart Device application in any way.

Comment: If I could use a newer version of VS , I would use but I need to develop a smart device application and vs2008 is the latest version of visual studio that I can develop a smart device application. so that is why I need configuration of ado.net or oledb through vs2008

Comment: But the web service does not relate to the Smart Device app, and you can only use EF in the Web Service, not the smart device app anyway.

Comment: Here my solution and project files photo http://i.hizliresim.com/4P1vj0.jpg
As you can see smart device project and wcf service together.  my web service need to be related because I will get datas to my smart application through web service.

Comment: Yes, you must create the Web Service project in another Solution in a newer Visual Studio version, and the reference the web service from your device project

Comment: I created my wcf service project on visual studio 2015 and   
ı need to reference it to vs 2008 (where I have smart devicea app project). Can you tell me which file I need to choose?. I go to reference > like here http://i.hizliresim.com/vbXvqr.jpg . Which file I should choose or what to do. Please can you help me ?